# What is "il gioco delle Bacole"?

Tags: meaning, regional

My Italian course book mentions 'il gioco delle Bacole'. It seems to be a children's game played with stones. There is one page of the book in which some children play it at Piazza Armerina (Sicily).

Can anyone please describe what this game is about? I have looked online using both English and Italian language search engines but I am none the wiser.

Comment: In which context does this game appears in your book? May you add some more information?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo or something? The word is absent from all main dictionaries. I also checked the two main Italian specialised dictionaries about games (Dossena and Angiolino-Sidoti), and it doesn't appear there either.

Comment: @DaG: It appears at [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000944.jpg).

Comment: @Charo: You're right, thanks. But it seems to just refer to the husk of French beans and a kind of berry. No mention of a game with stones, apparently.

Comment: Cfr., per il manuale di cui forse si parla: https://www.happylanguages.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Domani-3-unità-13.pdf

Comment: Grazie mille, @Benedetta! Probabilmente è questo. Siccome si parla di Piazza Armerina, magari è un gioco siciliano.

Comment: @Benedetta has provided a link to the page of the course book. The game is shown in illustration number 3.

Comment: @Charo: cercando su Google “gioco delle bacole”, viene fuori come primo risultato questa pagina di it.wiki: https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gioco_delle_cinque_pietre

Comment: Ecco quello che appare su [questo sito web](https://amontalbanoelicona.it/2015/05/08/gioco-e-ludibrio-alla-ricerca-dellindentita-passata), @Benedetta: «Così sul monte delle muse (da Helikon… Elicona) le ragazze erano abili con le baccole (cinque pietre), variante moderna del “pentelitha”, quel modo di giocare con gli Astragali preferito dalle fanciulle della Magna Grecia».

Comment: @RichardBeasley: Is this game played with 5 stones?

Comment: Interessante, @Charo! È la prima volta che vedo (e leggo di) questo gioco.

Comment: @DaG:  Is there a game called "penthelita" in your dictionaries about games? This game seems to be some kind of variant of "penthelita".

Comment: @Charo: The reference is very useful, but it has two oddities. The Wikipedia page itself does not mention the "bacole", and therefore we must trust that Google associated the two things correctly: it is something similar to what [happened here](https://xmau.com/wp/notiziole/2020/01/21/tartinville-e-google/).

Comment: Moreover, the Wikipedia article is quite incomplete, because it seems to talk about the game of astragali, but in reality it only speaks of pebbles and not [astragali](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/astragalo). (I'm not criticising you, @Charo! This is probably the right direction to investigate.)

Comment: @DaG: I'm not referring to Wikipedia, but to the other link in one of my previous comment.

Comment: @Charo: Good idea! Those dictionaries don't seem to register the word “penthelita”, but both register that game, or family of games. Dossena calls it _cinque noccioli_, while Angilino-Sidoti call it _cinque sassi_. They also list some regional names (_cincu_, _bichi_, _ossi_, _pescudde_ and so on), but unfortunately no _bacole_ or _baccole_; the nearest-sounding is the Roman version _breccole_. (As a Roman, I'm familiar with the word, but not as a game, but in general sense of “pebbles”.)

Comment: @DaG: Maybe we could try to ask [here](https://amontalbanoelicona.it/autori-2/)? (Francesca Bisbano is the author of the previously linked test about traditional games at Montalbano Elicona).